# How do we give input type as Reset and a Click event on Reset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

I have a Reset button with input type = reset. On click of the Reset button, I need all fields to clear first and then I have to execute a method.
So I am using a click event but not able to execute both with type reset.

```html
<button type="reset">Reset</button>                          // Line 1
<button (click)="resetView()" type="button">Reset</button>  // Line 2
```

```js
resetView(){
  // Some method
}
```

The first line is enabling only reset of fields. The second line is only hitting the resetView() method without clearing out the fields.
How do I include both the reset and resetView() method

Comment: Have you tried to combine them: `<button type="reset" (click)="resetView()">` ?

Comment: Yes, this is first executing the method and then resetting all fields. I want to first reset all fields and then execute method. @MaxXx1313

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways comes to my mind that form can be handled in angular:

1. using `form` tag:

```html
<form #myForm>
 <!-- here some other controls -->
 <button (click)="myForm.reset(); resetView()">Reset</button>
</form>
```

2. using `ngModel`:

```html
 <input [(ngModel)]="myInput1"/>
 <input [(ngModel)]="myInput2"/>
 <!-- here some other controls -->
 <button (click)="resetForm(); resetView()">Reset</button>
```

```js
resetForm(){
  this.myInput1 = '';
  this.myInput2 = '';
  // etc.
}
resetView(){
  // Some method
}
```

3. using `FormGroup`:

```html
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
 <input formGroupName="myInput1"/>
 <input formGroupName="myInput2"/>
 <!-- here some other controls -->
 <button (click)="resetForm(); resetView()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

```js
readonly myForm = new FormGroup({
  myInput1: new FormControl(''),
  myInput2: new FormControl(''),
  // etc.
});

resetForm(){
  this.myForm.reset();
}
resetView(){
  // Some method
}
```